# Facebook API - accessing photos

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have written a JS script that allows a user to choose a photo from their facebook profile for printing. When they select the image and submit the form, it passes a link to my php script which copies it (I assumed using the access token for permission).

My app is not public yet.

The FB API returns a link for the image. The link is in the form of: http://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t1.0-9/1926883_746836342049730_5714653518291139956_n.jpg (note that this is a private photo that supposedly only I can view).

I assumed that in order to access these photos if they were private, I'd need the access token. However, I went into chrome's incognito mode and IE, neither of which are logged into my FB account, I can see this "private" photo. Does this mean that I don't need the access token as long as I have the link?

I don't think it's another security flaw in FB's photos because the link does not seem available from anywhere other than an app with photo permissions.

What I'd like to know is if I need to use the access token somewhere in this process to "fetch" the image or if I just need to use the link. This will determine whether I need the facebook php library on my server or if I can use just the JS SDK.

To clarify, I'd like to know whether I need an access token to retrieve a private image from facebook's servers, or if the link is sufficient.

Comment: Please read this advice on asking good questions: [ask] and [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: Sounds like you have answered your own question.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know if it was going to be repeatable for everyone -can I count on this behavior. I knew it worked for me in this case, but I am building an application that uses this functionality so I wanted to be sure it was a feature and not a glitch. WizKid's answer and comments solved it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a security flaw. You can read about it at http://www.quora.com/Facebook-product/Are-Facebook-pictures-really-private-and-are-they-hosted-on-Facebook-servers which is linked from https://www.facebook.com/whitehat "Accessing photos via raw image URLs from our CDN (Content Delivery Network). One of our engineers explained has more details here"

Comment: So I can count on this working for everyone? All I have to do is get that link from a user and I don't need to worry about passing access tokens?

Comment: The url may stop working at any second. That is why you should use the API to get the url.

Comment: "Any Second" meaning within 45 seconds of my query? I'm passing the link from the JS to the PHP + retrieving the file on form submission.

Comment: As long as you don't store it you should be fine